# How to filter calendar events by attendee email

Tags: android, filter, android-calendar

my goal is to get all calendar events out of my calendar and filter it by an attendee who i am looking for. With other words, I want all events where Mr. Mayer is an attendee
I have resolved this problem to get my events. I have them in my cursor curCalendar But how can I filter the curCalendar by attendee email?
I was thinking of creating an array with all event Ids, or if i could delete rows of the cursor curCalendar. Well I need help. How can I filter my curCalendar by an special attendee
email...

if(! strEmailFilter.isEmpty()){

```
            //there is an Email Filter - look for a special Attendee within all Events...
            curCalendar.moveToFirst();
            index = curCalendar.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events._ID);
            strEventId = curCalendar.getString(index);
            strEmail = openCalendar.getEmailfromAttendee(this, strEventId);
            Integer i= 0;
            if (strEmail.equals(strEmailFilter)){
                //Attendee email is equal to filter email
                //Add row to CurCalendarGefiltert
                strEventsGefiltert [i] = strEventId;

            }
            while (curCalendar.moveToNext()) {
                i = i +1;
                index = curCalendar.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events._ID);
                strEventId = curCalendar.getString(index);
                strEmail = openCalendar.getEmailfromAttendee(this, strEventId);
                if (strEmail.equals(strEmailFilter)){
                    strEventsGefiltert [i] = strEventId;
                //  curCalendarGefiltert.

                }
            }

        }

                 MyCalendarAdapter myCalendaradapter = new MyCalendarAdapter (
                          this,
                          R.layout.terminzeile_google,
                          curCalendar,
                          new String[] {CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION},
                          new int[] {R.id.textViewTitle, R.id.textViewProjekt}

                          );





        /*
        myClientsadapter.setViewBinder(new MyDataAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {


                if(columnIndex == 13) {
                        String strBeginn = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                        int intbezahlt = cursor.getInt(13);
                        cb.setChecked(intbezahlt > 0);
                        return true;
                }

                String str = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                return false;
            }
        });


        */
        listViewTermine.setAdapter(myCalendaradapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search through the Attendees table using the content URI "CalendarContract.Attendees.CONTENT_URI" based on the eventId for each event found. Just capture the value for the event when you find a match.

So in short you need to write a similar method as the one your wrote to read events through the CalendarContract.

Check this link for more details on how to access attendees table:
https://android-dot-google-developers.appspot.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Attendees.html